# ZooKeeper vs Consul with solrcloud

Tags: apache-zookeeper, solrcloud, consul

I am a little unsure of the difference between using ZooKeeper and Consul with a SolrCloud solutions. 
Can I use Consul for configuration management and service discovery, instead of using ZooKeeper. 
Is there a reason why I would use both ZooKeeper and Consul? e.g. ZooKeeper for configuration management and Consul for service discovery.

Comment: AFAICT, no, Consul isn't supported with SolrCloud at all. Can you have two different consensus systems? Sure, but then you need to deal with the failure modes of each, handle situations where they disagree with each other, &c; I wouldn't at all advise it.

Comment: One of my colleagues told me that SolrCloud can not work without ZooKeeper.
ZooKeeper is a part of SolrCloud